# I want to freeze row in google sheet c2:i2 when a2="RED"

Tags: google-sheets

I want to lock all the rows in which column A has text=RED. Please help me as I am new to this

Comment: Google Sheets is too limited to allow that.

Comment: What do you mean by freezing (in the title) or locking (in the question)? Freezing prevents a row from scrolling. There's protection against editing. I don't know what "lock" is.

Comment: Actually I want to Lock (Protect) that row, so that shared user wont be able to edit that cells

Answer (score 0):

You can protect ranges in a script.  [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) is a link for the documentation.  Try iterating through the rows and checking the first value in each row to see if the text is equal to "RED".  If it is, add protection to that row.  The Google reference linked has example code for how to implement this.

Put this code in your onEdit(e) function, and these protected rows will be updated each time the spreadsheet is edited.  Hope this helps!